# Laravel : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, get

I have problem with laravel , in my localhost everthing is fine but on my shared hosting i got problem even is the same php version

For example : 
I want to get question title using $answer->question->title but i got error Trying to get property of non-object (View: /new/resources/views/users/show.blade.php)
But the project work fine in my localhost

Controller :

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $answers = \App\Answer::where('user_id','=',$user->id)
                                ->with(['survey'])
                                ->get();
        $survey = \App\Survey::pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();
        $question = \App\Question::pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();

            return view('users.show', compact('user','survey','answers','question'));
    }
```

View blade :

```
 <table class="table">
                                <thead class="thead-light">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>{{ __('Question') }}</th>
                                        <th>{{ __('Answers') }}</th>
                                        <th>{{ __('Creation Date') }}</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach($answers as $t)
                                    <tr> 
                                        <td> {{ $t->question->id }} </td>
                                        <td> {{ $t->answer }} </td>
                                        <td> {{$t->created_at}} </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

In my localhost is working fine but in shared hosting i got :

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /new/resources/views/users/show.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Trying to get property of non-object (0)

Please could you help me to fix that ?

Comment: Did you check to make sure all of your Models are uploaded as well?

Comment: Yes i did and i checked other pages everthing work only this page and i cleaned the cache

Comment: I tried `{{$t->question}}` i got array included the title id ... but when i tried `{{$t->question->title}}` i got the first error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query returning array. If you dump it out, you might find that it's an array and all you need is an array access `([])` instead of an object access `(->).`

Comment: Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: `$article->question['id']` like this

Answer (score 5):

Try calling it like this:

```
$article->question['title']
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

check if data in blade is array or object and check is array is parent object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).